# Searching a table both horizontally and vertically and printing the values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

sorry for the ambiguous title. I'm not quite sure how to name what I'm trying to do.
I have data in a worksheet that looks like this:
[image]

I would like to search for the smallest number in the range and write out the name on the y axis and the number. It then ignores this number and searches for the smallest number on the x axis as well. In that same row, it searches for the smallest value horizontally, excludes the number and then looks vertically as well. It continues this way until all possibilities are exhausted. Is this possible with Excel?
A sample output will be:

```
y5 : 40
x3: 60
y3: 90
x4: 80
y2 : 85
x3: 75
y1 : 70
```

and so on.

Comment: Of course it is possible with VBA, but -- what if there are ties?

Comment: @John Coleman, Ha yes,  it chooses one and simply continues

Comment: If there are ties then when you say "excludes the number" do you mean "excludes the *occurrence* of the number" or "excludes the number itself"?

Comment: @John Coleman, excludes the number itself in this case.

Comment: Just to be clear -- you mean that if the x3 column had two 40s then only 1 of them would be selected?

Comment: Yes, if two 40s are present only one would be selected. That cell will then be excluded from subsequent selection /query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem. You should be able to modify the following. To run it you need to include a reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` (Under `Tools/References` in the VBA editor) since it uses a dictionary data structure -- the natural choice to keep track of already picked numbers:

```
'The following code assumes than Nums is a 1-based 2-dimensional array

Function MinPath(Nums As Variant) As Variant
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim mins As Variant
    Dim PickedNums As New Dictionary
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim report As String
    Dim direction As String
    Dim num As Variant
    Dim min As Variant, min_i As Long, min_j As Long
    m = UBound(Nums, 1)
    n = UBound(Nums, 2)

    ReDim mins(1 To m * n)

    min = Nums(1, 1)
    min_i = 1
    min_j = 1
    For i = 1 To m
        For j = 1 To n
            If Nums(i, j) < min Then
                min = Nums(i, j)
                min_i = i
                min_j = j
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    PickedNums.Add min, 0
    counter = 1
    mins(counter) = Array(min_i, min_j, min)
    direction = "vertical"
    min = Empty

    Do While True
        If direction = "vertical" Then
            For i = 1 To m
                num = Nums(i, min_j)
                If Not PickedNums.Exists(num) Then
                    If IsEmpty(min) Then
                        min = num
                        min_i = i
                    ElseIf num < min Then
                        min = num
                        min_i = i
                    End If
                End If
            Next i

            If IsEmpty(min) Then
                ReDim Preserve mins(1 To counter)
                MinPath = mins
                Exit Function
            Else
                PickedNums.Add min, 0
                counter = counter + 1
                mins(counter) = Array(min_i, min_j, min)
                direction = "horizontal"
            End If
        Else
            'direction = horizontal case
            For j = 1 To n
                num = Nums(min_i, j)
                If Not PickedNums.Exists(num) Then
                    If IsEmpty(min) Then
                        min = num
                        min_j = j
                    ElseIf num < min Then
                        min = num
                        min_j = j
                    End If
                End If
            Next j

            If IsEmpty(min) Then
                ReDim Preserve mins(1 To counter)
                MinPath = mins
                Exit Function
            Else
                PickedNums.Add min, 0
                counter = counter + 1
                mins(counter) = Array(min_i, min_j, min)
                direction = "vertical"
            End If
        End If
    min = Empty
    Loop
End Function
```

The function repeatedly searches a either a row or a column (depending on the search direction) to find the smallest non-picked number. At the beginning of each pass the variable `min` is set to `Empty` until a non-picked number is encountered. If after a pass `min` is still `Empty` the function returns. This function returns an array of arrays where each array is of the form `Array(i,j,min)` (e.g. the values (5,3,40) in the first step). VBA's `Array` function returns a 0-based array so the `i` (row) coordinate is at index 0 and the `j` coordinate is at index 1. What you do with this data is up to you. For example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim mins As Variant

    mins = MinPath(Range("B2:F6").Value)
    n = UBound(mins)
    For i = 1 To n
        If i Mod 2 = 1 Then 'odd step
            Range("A7").Offset(i).Value = "y" & mins(i)(0) & ":"
        Else 'even step
            Range("A7").Offset(i).Value = "x" & mins(i)(1) & ":"
        End If
        Range("B7").Offset(i).Value = mins(i)(2)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: Hi, yip this works for the sample data provided. Could you please explain how it works? I'm trying to modify it for a larger 2 dimensional array but I'm having no luck. in  `report`   `y` and  `x` are strings which have an id_number in the cell preceding them. Is there a way to write this values to other area of the worksheet like so:  id_number_, y string_ y_value

Comment: I refactored the code a bit and added (a small amount of) explanation. The main function returns an array of data which records the row index, the column index and the value of each number chosen. Even though what you wanted to print uses only 1 of the 2 indices at each stage I figured that it was more flexible to have a function which doesn't throw any away information.